# How to remove failed macports software?

Tags: uninstall, macports, gimp

I was installing gimp using macport

But it takes me 2 hours to build and install the entire dependents.

So I stopped it. But no matter I use uninstall or clean command. It took me 2GB disk. I wonder how to free them? Or I need to finish install it and then uninstall?

Answer (score 10):

Try cleaning all the packages first.

```
sudo port clean --all all
```

You can also try

```
sudo port uninstall inactive
```

If those fail, add the -f flag to force the operation.

You might also be successful using.

```
sudo port -f install gimp
```

If you don't need the latest version, download the binary from the gimp website or try the native version http://gimp-app.sourceforge.net

If you have not installed any gtk2 dependents yer, you can try installing the native (non X11)  version using the +quartz flag.

Answer (score 0):

See the Macports guide on [port variants](http://guide.macports.org/#using.variants) to show what actions you can do on a port.

To clean up a port ie remove files used in the build do `port clean`

To remove a port that has been built do `port uninstall`

These work on a single port and will not act on more than one port.

Also gimp does take a long time to install. To show whether it is doing something, install the port verbosely `sudo port -v install gimp`